# Are Entropy results order-dependent when using SameTest

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, entropy

Mathematica's `Entropy` function is order-dependent when using the `SameTest` option.

That is:

```
Entropy[RandomSample[Range[11]], SameTest->(Abs[#1-#2]>1&) ]
```

will give different results many times.

I assume that this is because `Entropy[]` is in fact `Union`-izing the list, but, unlike `Union`, it is actually replacing one of the `SameTest` values with the other, and this replacement is order sensitive.

Is this a bug or is it the expected behaviour?

Comment: @berniethejet: At the risk of sounding tautological, questions on StackOverflow need to have a question in them, else they tend to get closed. So I rephrased your bug report in the form of a question.

Comment: From some experimentation, it seems a permutation of `Range[n]` will give one result when the first item in the list is either 1 or n, and a different result the rest of the time.  Probably worth an email to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: @yoda.  Ok, thanks, I don't mind.  I think this requirement is a little unnecessary, reducing the value of the forum a little bit.  But I am sure the creators had their reasons.  Still better than the Mathematica Usenet forum!

Comment: @Brett: what do you mean?  How are you doing the permutation?  You mean RandomSample[{1 2 3}] does something different than Range[{2,3,4}]???

Comment: Check the output from `Union /@ GatherBy[{First[#], 
      N@Entropy[#, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] > 1 &)]} & /@ 
    Permutations[Range[5]], Last][[All, All, 1]]`.

Comment: @Brett:  I think that this is just an artifact of the same issue, a boundary issue based on the path dependency of the SameTest.  That is, your same code, just modifying the Range, gives the expected answer: Union /@ GatherBy[{First[#], 
      N[Entropy[#, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] > 1 &)]]} & /@ 
    Permutations[Range[1, 9, 2]], Last][[All, All, 1]].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see using `Trace[ ]` that the `Entropy[ ]` function ends up using `Tally[ ]` for counting the frequency of each state (numbers in this case).

So for example

```
 Entropy[{1,2,3,4}, SameTest->(Abs[#1-#2]>1&)]
```

calls

```
 Tally[{1,2,3,4}, SameTest->(Abs[#1-#2]>1&)]
```

which gives

```
 -> {{1, 3}, {2, 1}}
```

because it groups {1,3,4} and {2}

But if you ask for

```
 Tally[{2,1,3,4}, SameTest->(Abs[#1-#2]>1&)]
```

you get

```
  -> {{2, 2}, {1, 2}}
```

because it groups {2,4} and {1,3}

Resulting in a different states distribution (2,2) vs (3,1) before, and hence in a different entropy value.

I think the problem arises because your SameTest is not partitioning the domain in two equivalence classes, as it should.

**Edit**

Just reformulating the last sentence:

Mma assumes that

```
a === b && b === c  Implies a === c
```

which is not true in your case. For example

```
2 === 4 && 4 === 1  but  2 !=== 1
```

Comment: Thank you belisarius for this analysis, this is very interesting.  I suspect that this results in Entropy then actually giving the wrong answer -as opposed to just a statistically wrong answer - whenever SameTest is used in an Euclidian fashion.

Comment: @bernie Yep. A _distance_ will not _usually_ split the domain in equivalence classes

Comment: Well, so then this isn't a bug of Entropy.  I was trying to get a measure of entropy in the original sense that I had learned it in physics where particles have more entropy the more evenly distributed they are in space, and less when they are concentrated.  I thought distance would be sufficient, but clearly I am wrong...

Comment: @bernie Toy may read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_in_thermodynamics_and_information_theory